# phpqrcode library return image as a string

Tags: php

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/, is a great library but i can't find **how to return the png image as a string**, the basic examples are

```
QRcode::png('code data text', 'filename.png'); // creates file 
QRcode::png('some othertext 1234'); // creates code image and outputs it directly into browser
```

i checked the documentation and nothing, help! :B

Comment: What do you mean by "return the png image as a string"?

Comment: You could probably do something with output buffering, but if the developers were sane the library should support this

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Not output directly or save to a file, but return a string in a variable

Comment: Do you mean base64 encoded, or just the raw data?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw, raw data!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
ob_start();
QRCode::png('text', null);
$imageString = base64_encode( ob_get_contents() );
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: this works!, i dont know why class developers dont bring a basic usage function like this... anyway THANKS a Lot!!

Comment: You're welcome! You'd certainly think that they would, I can't imagine that that wouldn't be a common usage.

Comment: update :: this code can't be useful cuz QRCode::png method sends Header("Content-type: image/png");, anyway thanks

Comment: So strip that header or modify the code so it doesn't send that.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Unfortunately the HTTP header overwrites the current one and removing the image one still requires you re-set the original one which, depending on the document may not always be the same so you would need to determine what it was, and pretty soon the entire thing turns into a hacked together spaghetti code for something really not worth it. So, I opted to just use the PHP PEAR class https://wiki.php.net/pear/packages/image_qrcode which DOES allow returning the data. That take SourceForge! Btw @iim.hlk you should accept his answer as it technically does as you asked.

Comment: @iim.hlk: If you simply pass null into the second argument (`$filename`) into the `png()` method the headers won't be sent and the answer should work.

Answer (score 8):

```
$qrTempDir = 'path/to/your/temp';
$filePath = $qrTempDir.'/'.uniqid();

QRcode::png('some text', $filePath);
$qrImage = file_get_contents($filePath);

unlink($filePath);
```

This should be what you're looking for. You can extend it to show an image like that:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($qrImage) ?>" />
```

Unfortunately, the library does not support any other method at the moment, because calling the QRcode::png function without the file parameter not only makes it send those headers, but it also exits the code execution, so there is no retracting or overwriting the headers.

Comment: It helped me out in a major way, thanks for the solution and for clarifying the whole situation. I spent an afternoon trying to grab it with the output buffer, to no avail.

Comment: As did I, at that time.

Comment: I tried every other thing here and there and this one was the only that really worked for me. Thanks

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it writes the file to disk.  If you're encoding something sensitive, like a TOTP seed URL, you don't really want these hanging around.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem as @iim.hlk

This is what i did slightly modified @Lusitanian his answer to this

```
ob_start();
QRCode::png($string);
$imageString = base64_encode( ob_get_clean() );
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

This fixes the header issue by simply overwriting it. Not clean or anything but it works for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
include '../phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
$content = "any content";
ob_start();
QRcode::png($content);
$result_qr_content_in_png = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// PHPQRCode change the content-type into image/png... we change it again into html
header("Content-type: text/html");
$result_qr_content_in_base64 =  base64_encode($result_qr_content_in_png);
```

then in your html file

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,$result_qr_content_in_base64'"/>
```

Comment: Can confirm it works just fine.
Generates the image and embeds it into the HTML body.
Checked with Gmail and it works perfectly.
Also uses phpqrcode library.