# Capturing PNG stream with PHP output buffer

Tags: php, stream, output-buffering

I am currently attempting to write a web service that generates a QR code for a given string. I am using PHP QR Code (http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) to generate the QR code, like this:

```
QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
```

Result: a PNG stream of the QR Code is displayed on the screen.
As this is a void function that outputs directly to the browser, this prevents me from properly returning the image.

I would like to capture the PNG stream with PHP's output buffer and have my web service return this captured image.
I have set up the following test code on a plain php page for testing purposes:

```
include('/vendor/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

$scancode = "testcode";

ob_implicit_flush(false); //just in case
ob_start();
QRcode::png($scancode);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo "--" . $output . "--";
die();
```

However, when I run the code the buffer does not work as I had planned. No matter what I do, a broken image is always displayed as soon as I call the function. When I remove the output buffer code the QR code is rendered on the screen.

Why is some of my output not being captured?

Edit: related: [phpqrcode library return image as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352334/phpqrcode-library-return-image-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Remove  **header("content-type:image/png");**

to get it worked with output buffering.

Later you can echo

**header("content-type:image/png");**  and your captured output to show the image

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, that makes sense. How would I do this in the context of my above code though? I have tried adding header_remove("content-type:image/png") but to no avail. I have to say I don't know 100% how exactly this all works in the background. I take it I would have to modify the function that generates the image and try to strip the header in there?